# Having trouble with a basic age check in Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Here is my current code:

```
if (ageCheck < 18) {
    alert("YOU ARE TOO YOUNG");
} else if (ageCheck => 18) {
    alert("WELCOME");
} else {
    alert("test");
}


ageCheck();
```

The problem is that when running this and I put in random words rather then give me "test" it gives me "Welcome". How do I make it so that when I enter in something other then a number it runs the else part and gives me "test"?

Comment: Use correct [Comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators). Its `>=` not `=>` ,

Comment: `else if (ageCheck >= 18) {`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change else if statement to,

```
} else if (ageCheck >= 18) {
```

`greater than or equal to` is represented by `>=`

Comment: @AlexanderBishop In that case can you please accept the answer for stack overflow community

Comment: Sure thing, sorry I didn't before I'm new to this site. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add ane more check first, before comparing the number with 18?

```
if(isNaN(parseInt(ageCheck))) alert('not a number')
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe the below function can help  you

```
if (isNaN(ageCheck)) {
     alert("test"); }
else if (ageCheck < 18) {
    alert("YOU ARE TOO YOUNG");
} else if (ageCheck >= 18) {
    alert("WELCOME");
}
```

isNaN will check, whether its a number or not first

Comment: @dearDownVoter - care to explain the downvote please.